# interpreting correlative statistics table (stata)

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, linear-regression

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWJt.jpg)

Hello,

my professor sent this table to me and I am supposed to interpret the results. However, I do not really know what exactly he actually computed (using stata, which I don't have access to), I only got this table. I assume that it is a regression analysis (student's t-distribution?) to determine the effects of "Reference Pricing" (a measure of pharmaceutical regulation) on the other variables stated.

Is this correct:

First (first row, first column), we check whether life expectancy is affected by Reference Pricing. Second (first row, second column), we check whether life expectancy is affected by Reference Pricing, even when share of 65+ years population is being controlled for. 
Third (first row, third column), we check whether life expectancy is affected by Reference Pricing when share of population of 65+ years and log GDP per capita is being controlled for.

Are my assumptions correct or am I completely off? 
What exactly is the row "constant" supposed to tell me?

Please help me interpret this, I'm sorry if it seems obvious; I'm a business student and have never really done this before. 
Thanks a lot in advance.